# How to close window created with Process.Start()

Tags: .net, winapi, process

I open file explorer window from my application. I do it in the following manner:

```
var si = new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe", Path);
si.UseShellExecute = true;
var p = Process.Start(si);
p.WaitForInputIdle();
_hwnd = Window.FindWindow("CabinetWClass", null);
```

That part works. Now, the p.HasExited is already true. I am not sure why is that, but I assume that file explorer is not an ordinary process.

Anyway, I tried `p.Close()`, `p.CloseMainWindow()`, `p.Kill()` and nothing worked

I also imported DestroyWindow:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool DestroyWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

and used it like this:

```
var result = Window.DestroyWindow(_hwnd);
```

but that has no effect either (_hwnd is a correct non-zero handle)...

How can I close this window?

Answer (score 1):

Destroying other processes resources unexpectedly causes unpredictable behavior... Also, you are relying on details like window classes here. Very unstable code, I hope I will never get this product onto my machine.

Anyway, you can "steer" Windows Explorer using reliable and documented APIs using COM. I'm very rusty with this technique but I can point you in the right direction: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12029/Automate-the-Active-Windows-Explorer-or-Internet-E (The article is both about IE and Windows Explorer because they share lots of common infrastructure).

.NET can use the COM APIs, too. The code sometimes looks much more nicely then.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. The thing that I want to achieve is to embed a file explorer into my application and strip down some of the menus/buttons from it...And od not worry, you will not get this product on your machine...it's just for testing.

Comment: I'm sure various parts of explorer can be hosted the official way. Think of the file-save dialog - it host a Windows Explorer and supports all the usual drag and drop as well as shell extensions.